# AngularJS SEO Page 404 Header Status Code

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-404

We are working in a project which uses Symfony2 + AngularJS.
Each one in a different domain (api.domain for Symfony2 and www.domain for the Angular project).

Now we are focusing on the SEO part. We use Prerender.io to create static snapshots to serve a good HTML Raw page to crawlers.

But the problem is when serving the "404 Page" on Angular:

```
$urlRouterProvider
                  .otherwise('/404');
```

The thing is, **what we do is redirecting a nonexistent page to our "404 Page" with a 200 Header Status Code, which is very bad for SEO purposes...**

Since AngularJS is not capable of generating, we have already tried 2 things:

**1. Use a redirection with htaccess / Apache:**

```
 RedirectMatch 404 "/404"
```

**2. Call to a web service which return us a 404 error:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /do-not-access was not found on this server.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And for the AngularJS side we tried to throw the header status code without success:

```
return $http.get(ENV.apiEndpoint + '/do-not-access');
```

**None of this worked for us...**

We also though about using a second "404 Page". The idea was redirecting our first 404 page to this second 404 page via htaccess with a 404 status code, but we think that will not work due to AngularJS internal redirection:

```
200 -> 301 -> 404
```

PS: I found: [AngularJS html5mode and hard 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525828/angularjs-html5mode-and-hard-404) which says "we have to configure our server to make a routing exception for your custom 404 page" but we really have no clue how to do it...

Are we focusing in a bad way?

There is other option?

How we can handle it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that **prerender.io** offers a way to handle **http header status**.

For example, for a **404 page** we just need to **add this meta tag into our head tag**:

```
<meta name="prerender-status-code" content="404">
```

Docs: https://prerender.io/documentation/best-practices

Comment: But prerender.io is not free. Without using prerender.io, how can i resolve this problem ? Thanks you.